# Grails filter to catch defaultAction, when the default action is not index

Tags: grails

In a controller I have ...

```
class TestController {

    static defaultAction = "custom"

    // ...

    def custom() {

        // ...
```

So when I hit the app on http://localhost:8080/test

It defaults to the custom method

I've set up a filter with

```
class TestDriveControlFilters {


    def filters = {

        contextControl(controller:'test', action:'custom') {
            before = {
```

But this is only hit on /test/custom 
not on /test or /test/

How do I set up the filter in a nice way to catch both.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error :)

```
contextControl(controller:'test', action:'custom|') {
```

The addition of the pipe in the regex is the key to matching the null string